# com.android.camera.action.CROP sets wallpaper on Motorola Defy

Tags: java, android, image-processing, android-intent

I'm working on an Android 2.1+ app and trying to take a photo and then send the results of that intent to a crop function. It seems to work on the Sony Ericsson xmp, but when i put it on a Moto Defy, the crop function fails because it is seemingly ignoring the file name i put in for the data, and instead looks at `/data/data/com.motorola.gallery/files/temp-wallpaper` for some reason. This has the result of the crop function not returning with any data, and the image i just took gets set as the wallpaper image of the phone! 
Here's some sample code:

```
public static final String SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator;
public static final String SD_CARD_TEMP_ORIG = SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR + "origPhoto.jpg";
public static final String SD_CARD_TEMP_CROP = SD_CARD_TEMP_DIR + "croppedPhoto.jpg";

Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.SD_CARD_TEMP_ORIG)), "image/*");
intent.putExtra("crop", true);
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 512);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 512);
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.SD_CARD_TEMP_CROP)));
```

The output from this is something like this:

```
INFO/ActivityManager(1242): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=file:///sdcard/origPhoto.jpg typ=image/* cmp=com.motorola.gallery/.CropImage (has extras) }
INFO/ActivityManager(1242): Start proc com.motorola.gallery:CropImage for activity com.motorola.gallery/.CropImage: pid=25733 uid=10014 gids={1015, 9003, 9007, 9008, 2001, 3003}
WARN/CropImage(25733): CropImg mBitmap was null, retreive frm URIfile:///sdcard/origPhoto.jpg
ERROR/CropImage(25733): got IOException java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.motorola.gallery/files/temp-wallpaper 
INFO/ActivityManager(1242): Displayed activity com.motorola.gallery/.CropImage: 5664 ms (total 5664 ms)
WARN/System.err(25672): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/croppedPhoto.jpg
DEBUG/(25672): unable to unlink '/sdcard/croppedPhoto.jpg': No such file or directory (errno=2)
```

Does anyone have any experience with this issue, or ideas for a work around?

Comment: @Elrond: The `com.android.camera.action.CROP` `Intent` action is not part of the Android SDK. There is no guarantee that it will work on any device.

Comment: I had come across this point elsewhere, which is why i wanted to know if there was alternatively some work around?

Comment: Write yourself an image-cropping activity. Or, see if somebody already has written one that is available as open source.

Comment: Related: [Cropping Picture Issue on Droid X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3701530)

Answer (score 3):

I'd stay away from the Intent you're using, because it isn't standard, so may not be supported everywhere,

From the extra-data you're using, I believe you're doing a fixed-size crop, and don't need any user input. This makes the solution quite simple, as long as you don't run out of memory.

1. Load the image via [BitmapFactory.decodeFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29). You can pass in a [BitmapFactory.options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) object to optionally scale the image at load time.
2. Create a cropped bitmap with [Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
3. Write it out to disk with [Bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress%28android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat,%20int,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Comment: It is a fixed-size crop, but that doesn't mean i don't need user input. The user is asked to position and/or resize the crop region in the appropriate place on the image. For what it's worth i ended up using the solution outlined on http://www.walletapp.net/crop-image which works a treat!

Comment: @Elroid That link's rotted, but is still available via Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120219104844/http://www.walletapp.net/crop-image which links to this github repo: https://github.com/biokys/cropimage